# Why am I getting a Could not parse the remainder error when using AJAX with Django templates?

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

Here is my code using ajax in my code

View

```
def filter_data(request):
    categories = request.GET.getlist('category[]')
    brands = request.GET.getlist('brand[]')

    allProducts = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id').distinct()
    if len(categories) > 0:
        allProducts = allProducts.filter(Categories__id__in=categories).distinct()

    if len(brands) > 0:
        allProducts = allProducts.filter(Brand__id__in=brands).distinct()


    t = render_to_string('ajax/shop.html', {'product': allProducts})

    return JsonResponse({'data': t})
```

Adding script to the HTML file

```
{% block script%}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".filter-checkbox").on('click', function(){
            var filter_object={};
            $(".filter-checkbox").each(function(index,ele){
                var filter_value=$(this).val();
                var filter_key=$(this).data('filter');
                console.log(filter_key,filter_value);
                filter_object[filter_key]=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[data-filter='+filter_key+']:checked')).map(function(el){
                     return el.value;
                });
            });
            $.ajax({
                url:'{% url filter-data %}',
                data:filter_object,
                dataType:'json',            
                success:function(res){              
                    $("#filteredProducts").html(res.data);              
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

URL

```
    path('shop/filter-data',filter_data,name='filter-data'),
```

Got an unexpected eeror

**Error during template rendering**

**Could not parse the remainder: '-data' from 'filter-data'**

```
 url:'{% url filter-data %}'
```

Got an error in my script tag

So i changed the url to following the below code

```
$.ajax({
                url:'{% url 'filter-data' %}',
                data:filter_object,
                dataType:'json',            
                success:function(res){              
                    $("#filteredProducts").html(res.data);
```

but got an error in the HTML file please check the below image

[image: Image of the error]

Comment: try `url:'{% url '+ filter-data +' %}'`

Comment: I tried to **url:'{% url '+ filter-data +' %}',** but got an error **Reverse for '+ filter-data +' not found. '+ filter-data +' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

Comment: try this `'{% url "filter-data" %}'`

Comment: ok bro no error in the URL but filtering is not working bro